# Restrict user to switch branch on a local repository

Tags: git

In my local repository ( which is inside a shared environment) i have two kind of sources " X " and " Y " for each i created 2 different branches " X " and " Y " is there a way to stop a user working on the "Y" branch from switching to the "X" branch

Comment: Why you care about the user switching to whatever branch he wants? He'll be working locally.

Comment: because the local area is shared between many users

Comment: So you've got a git repository on one disk, one index, and multiple users are accessing this repo and index?

Comment: Actually it's an environment ( Unix ) shared between many users

Comment: "Shared" how? SMB? Or terminals using the same disk? If you want help you need to paint a complete picture.

Comment: It's a Unix virtual machine

Comment: Ok, you never actually answered this question: "So you've got a git repository on one disk, one index, and multiple users are accessing this repo and index?"  If the answer is yes - regardless of whether that's because the repo is physically in a "shared environment" - that is the wrong way to use git

Comment: we're migrating from ClearCase to GIT and  there's a constraint concerning some sources in UNIX because it's a shared environment ( unix virtual machine) where i've got my repo on one disk one index and multiple users. i tought about using pre-commit hook even if a user switches to a branch where he shouldn't be he can't commit but the problem this can be eeasily bypassed by --no-verify

Comment: by making git config file read only can i prevent switching to another branch ?@MarkAdelsberger

Answer (score -1):

You can provide restricted access to that particular branch on the remote. If you're using `Github` for remote hosting, then you can easily configure it to do so. As far as restricting switching on the local branch is concerned, that is not possible. It shouldn't matter since that particular user won't be able to push the changes to remote anyway.